# Mysql stuck on yellow color in Xampp mac

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

i was working on Xampp to access phpmyadmin but suddenly the mysql turned yellow and never start again. My mac is 2017 MacOS montery( 12.5.1 )
[here the pic shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOcC2.png)

and this is the version of Xampp  8.1.6 / PHP 8.1.6
as you all see at the pic it's yellow never turned green

ERROR: Failed to start "mysql": cannot start service: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 263: kill: No such process
the error above shows after turned red

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Was working fine and working on my PHP project and this happens all of the sudden.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apachectl stop` in Terminal and then restart it in XAMMP.

Comment: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service
Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified service ->> this error shows